# Expected return of find STL algorithm

Tags: c++, stl

```
list< int > a;

list < int > ::iterator it;

it = a.begin();

it=a.insert(it,10);
it=a.insert(it,210);
it=a.insert(it,310);
it=a.insert(it,410);
it=a.insert(it,510);


it = find(a.begin(),a.end(),180);

cout << *it << endl;
```

In this program the value 180 is not present in this list. So as per the find STL algorithm it should return the last value, but when I print this value it is coming something garbage. Seems like the iterator is pointing to some other location. Please help me spot my error.

Comment: `end()` is not the last item in the container, it is a magic marker representing one past the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::find` returns `end()` if element is not found in STL container, dereference `end()` is undefined behavior.

You need to test iterator `it` before dereference it:

```
it = find(a.begin(), a.end(), 180);
if (it != a.end())
{
  cout << *it << endl;
}
```

§ 25.2.5

> Returns: The first iterator i in the range [first,last) for which the following corresponding conditions hold: *i == value, pred(*i) != false, pred(*i) == false. Returns last if no such iterator is found.

range `[first,last)` is half open range, `last` means `end()` not last element in container.

Comment: return value: - An iterator to the first element in the range that compares equal to val.
If no elements match, the function returns last....this is what the find c++ webpage says

Comment: or the last means `end()` in this context

Comment: Nope, they have given the code for find, which indeed means that it is the last element, [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)

Comment: @anup.stackoverflow, `last` in this case means the parameter you passed in for `last` to the function. Normally this is `end()` which should never be dereferenced - that's why the `find` function stops searching before it hits `last`.

Comment: @MarkRansom...Yup, you are perfect!...Dont know how I missed this fact. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`a.end()` is not an iterator to the last value but an iterator that is *past* the last element in the list. It should never be printed or accessed in any way. In the case of `std::find`, you should compare the return value to the end iterator. If it matches, there is no element in that container that matches the requested value.

```
it = find(a.begin(),a.end(),180);
if( a.end() == it ) { // using Yoda conditional
    cout << "no element matching value.." << endl;
} else {
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```